# JAVA : How to add more than one member to a group in LDAP

Tags: java, ldap

I am try to create a group & add a few users to the group.I can add a single member.

When I try to add more than one member,The result is not as I am expected.

**Java Code:**

```
public static DirContext createGroup(String groupName,ArrayList<String> members,DirContext ctx) {

    try {

    Attributes attrs = new BasicAttributes(true); 
    Attribute objclass = new BasicAttribute("objectClass");
    objclass.add("top");
    objclass.add("groupOfNames");

    Attribute groupname = new BasicAttribute("cn", groupName);

    attrs.put(objclass);
    attrs.put(groupname);

    Attribute memberAtt;

    for (int i = 0;i<members.size();i++) 
    { 
        memberAtt = new BasicAttribute("member", members.get(i));
        attrs.put(memberAtt);
    }

    ctx.createSubcontext("cn="+groupName+",ou=Groups", attrs);
    } catch (NamingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return ctx;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a new BasicAttribute with the same attribute name and a single value within your loop.
You should use `memberAtt.add(members.get(i))` to add values to the memberAtt BasicAttribute.

Comment: Thank you so much @Ludovic poitou .You saved my day :)